# Queuable interface calls many times

Tags: apex, queueable-interface, asyncapexjob, queueable-apex

I'm calling a queuable interface via a trigger afterupdate. this queuable interface is allowing callouts to an external webservice ( Database.AllowsCallouts ).

When I check the apex jobs, I found many jobs executed related to this queuable interface. Is there an explanation to this?

=== Adding Context from Comments ==

When I create a case and updated it with field `ITA_IFM_Operation_Type__c == 'MODIFICATION' and ITA_IFM_SAP_Status__c =='Sent'` I add the case Id to caseIDS set of IDs.

And then

```
if  (!casesIDs.isEmpty()){ 
   myQueuableInterface updateCaseJob = new myQueuableInterface (casesIDs); 
  ID myJobID = System.enqueueJob(updateCaseJob); 
}
```

Comment: There could be legitimate reasons for a trigger to run more than once. Can you add context to your questions, please?

Comment: I think we need more complete code like that, but I added your comments to the original question so it's easier to read

Answer (score 1):

[From the doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_enqueueJob), each `System.enqueueJob()` creates an `AsyncApexJob` object which is what shows in the job monitoring pages

> enqueueJob(queueableObj)
>
> Adds a job to the Apex job queue that corresponds to the specified
>   queueable class and returns the job ID.

Comment: So this number of calls can be caused from the trigger calls... !! because i'm queueing the job in the trigger ID myJobID = System.enqueueJob(updateCaseJob);

Comment: @LoveLace -- yes - that would do it. Hopefully you are bulkifying the instantiation of the queueable class. You might also look at Appleman's Async pattern using queueables in his 3rd Edition, chapter 7 for a generalized mechanism usable by any aspect of your org - batchables, VF, REST services, triggers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There seems many concurrent call on your trigger.
Your job updates the case then trigger is executed , queues the job again then it updates the case again ....
You should check old new values or make sure your update context is executed once.

Comment: Yes you right.. I have many workflow fields updates and process builder updating the record.

Comment: I made a comparative between the old/new values. Now I got the job firing twice. I checked all the possible values to not relaunch the trigger. Could it be a cause of an update call I made on the job apex class?

Comment: Is there any workflow on the object? Could that be the reason?